# What is the F# equivalent of this C# code?

Tags: f#

I used VB.Net when I started in C# there was a code translating site. It would be good to have this for F#

I wrote this C# code

```
public interface IData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
}
public interface IVertex : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
public abstract class Vertex<IData>
{
    public IData Properties { get; set; }

    public Vertex()   {   }
    public Vertex(IData Properties)
    {
        this.Properties = Properties ;
    }

    public string Tipo { get { return typeof(IData).Name; } }
}
public class Data_Person : IData
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person : Vertex<Data_Person>, IVertex
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Properties = new Data_Person();
    }
    public Person(Data_Person Properties) : base(Properties)
    {  }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class EdgeLink<ISourceVertex, IEdgeData, ITargetVertex>
{
    public EdgeLink()
    {        }
    public EdgeLink(ISourceVertex In, IEdgeData Edge, ITargetVertex Out)
    {
        this.In = In;
        this.Properties = Edge;
        this.Out = Out;
    }

    public ISourceVertex In { get; set; }
    public IEdgeData Properties { get; set; }
    public ITargetVertex Out { get; set; }

    //public LoadStatus LoadStatus { get; set; } = LoadStatus.Uknown;
}
```

I am trying to do the same, but in F#.

**How to 'translate' this to F# ?**

I tried to translate, but it got messed, so far I have

```
type IData = 
    inherit INotifyPropertyChanged
    abstract member ID: Guid with get, set

type IEdgeData = 
    inherit IData

type IVertex =
    inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

type ISourceVertex =
    inherit IVertex

type ITargetVertex = 
    interface 
        inherit IVertex
    end
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a free translation service. Please try to do it yourself, and if you encounter any specific problems, ask questions about them.

Comment: I helped a lot of people,when I don't want to help I pass to another question; and think that somebody who knows F# syntax better than me can easily answer this.

Comment: I used VB.Net when i started in C# there was a code translating site. It would be good to have this for F#

Comment: Which part is causing you trouble?  Are you trying to do a direct port or make an F# idiomatic version equivalent to the C# code?  Converting VB.net to C# is a little different from converting C# to F#, since F# is a functional-first language and things like setters on properties, while supported, would generally be avoided.

Comment: I am having trouble specially with the `event PropertyChangedEventHandler` and `Vertex<Data_Person>, IVertex`

Comment: I used VB.Net when I started in C# there was a code translating site. It would be good to have this for F#

Comment: Your translation attempt has `IEdgeData`, `ISourceVertex`, and `ITargetVertex`, but your original code doesn't have those. What's up with that? Also, your translation attempt does compile fine, there are no problems in it. So what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Yes, I put the attempt I done so far, the rest, become messy, I did not have success in syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the comments indicate that you're having trouble with the event and the generic type, here's how you would convert those, specifically:

```
open System
open System.ComponentModel

type IData =
    inherit INotifyPropertyChanged
    abstract member ID: Guid

type IVertex = inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

[<AbstractClass>]
type Vertex<'data when 'data :> IData> (properties: 'data) =
    member __.Properties = properties
    member __.Tipo = typeof<'data>.Name

type DataPerson (id, balance, name) =
    let propertyChanged = Event<_,_>()
    member __.ID = id
    member __.Balance = balance
    member __.Name = name
    interface IData with
        member __.ID = id
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member __.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
```

You just need a generic type variable `'data` constrained to be an `IData` for the `Vertex` class and an F# `Event<_,_>` with a [] property for the `PropertyChanged` event.

Note, I left out the setters on the properties here.  You can easily add them back if you really need them.

**EDIT**

Adding the person class:

```
type Person (person) =
    inherit Vertex<DataPerson>(person)
    let propertyChanged = Event<_,_>()
    interface IVertex with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding optional parameters in constructors (I also made the `Vertex.Properties` property mutable this time, since it wouldn't make much sense to keep it immutable if you could instantiate the class with it uninitialized).  I probably wouldn't do it this way in a pure-F# solution, but this is a more direct representation of the original C# code:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Vertex<'data when 'data :> IData> (?properties: 'data) =
    let vertexProperties = defaultArg properties Unchecked.defaultof<'data>
    member val Properties = vertexProperties with get,set
    member __.Tipo = typeof<'data>.Name

type DataPerson (id, balance, name) =
    let propertyChanged = Event<_,_>()
    member __.ID = id
    member __.Balance = balance
    member __.Name = name
    interface IData with
        member __.ID = id
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member __.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

type Person (?person) =
    inherit Vertex<DataPerson>(defaultArg person Unchecked.defaultof<DataPerson>)
    let propertyChanged = Event<_,_>()     
    interface IVertex with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
```

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! I will give a try on this code and tell here.

Comment: :) missing the trouble part for me `public class Person : Vertex<Data_Person>, IVertex`

Comment: @Tony I thought the missing piece there was the constrained generic type on the `Vertex` class, so I didn't included `Person` in the original example, but I've added it for clarity.

Comment: Let me bother you a little more: How about the `Person()` and `Person(Data_Person Properties) : base(Properties)`

 Can this also be added? (The parameter-less constructor and the Properties constructor)

Comment: I've added a second edit that shows the usage of optional parameters.  This allows you to call the `Person` constructor without passing the `DataPerson` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added that parameterless in C# because JSON required it to instanciate. Otherwise I would be fine with the parameter constructor.

Comment: If you really need a truly parameterless constructor, you can add a line in the `Person` class after the `let propertyChanged = ...` that declares an overload like `new () = Person(Unchecked.defaultof<DataPerson>)`.

Comment: I tried this because I am trying to create a way of a Strongly Typed Graph access, using Neo4j GrapheneDB Database, but when I began I felt that aside from the C# code (I wrote easily) in F# I had difficulty to find all those details, and like hearing, "you must use an F# way to do that". But to ensure I put the question here asking for this equivalent code. Now I have my F# version assured. No need to C# Class Library. And can try to write a more idiomatic F# way later. Thanks!